# why is ag-grid getFilterInstance so slow - with custom headers

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

see example codesandbox:

#### Slow when using custom headers (by 14 seconds)

https://codesandbox.io/s/ag-grid-react-getfilterinstance-slow-with-custom-headers-welt9?file=/src/Grid/Grid.tsx

**steps:**

1. ***(Click) toggle to display filters***
2. (Type) Toyota
3. wait filter update (also slow)
4. (click) getFilter
5. WAIT 10 seconds or more for the console.log to display...

**This example uses custom headers but adding agColumnHeader to frameworkComponents**

```
const frameworkComponents = {
  agColumnHeader: AgColumnHeader
};
```

**Also on button click - toggles the filters to be true**

```
colDef.floatingFilter = !colDef.floatingFilter;
colDef.filter = "agTextColumnFilter";
```

#### Faster when NOT using custom headers

https://codesandbox.io/s/ag-grid-react-getfilterinstance-fast-forked-sfd3x?file=/src/Grid/Grid.tsx:957-1523

**steps:**

1. ***(Click) Filter icon***
2. (Type) Toyota
3. wait filter update (also slow)
4. (click) getFilter
5. WAIT 10 seconds or more for the console.log to display...

**This example simply defaults the floatingFilter to true on load but does not have customisation on column headers.**

```
 const defaultColDef: TColumn = {
    filter: "agTextColumnFilter",
    floatingFilter: true
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

so it turns out its **codesandbox** - ridiculously slow.
I tested this in my local environment and its fast.
What a let down.